# JSF not null condition

Tags: jsf, el

Using JSF & EL, I'm basically trying to check if a variable is null (or not).

Here is a code snippet:

```
<p:dataGrid value="#{bean.graphiques}"
            var="graphique"
            rows="1" columns="3">
    <c:if test="#{not empty graphique}">
        <p:chart type="line" model="#{graphique}"/>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="#{empty graphique}">
        <p:outputLabel>
            Add a new chart.
        </p:outputLabel>
    </c:if>
</p:dataGrid>
```

First check, `#{not empty graphique}` is always false, even if `graphique` is not null. I tried with `#{graphique ne null}` and `#{graphique != null}`, but it's false, too.

When I remove the `c:if` statement, the chart is displayed. Thus, `graphique` is not null.

I looked for a solution on a lot of websites - including SO - but didn't manage to find a solution.

Do you know what's going on and how to solve my problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks to @BalusC, I understand what my problem actually is. I'll try to fix it, then post a correct answer.

Comment: Abrikot, it's already answered.

Comment: Well, I thought I had already tried Raul Cuth's answer. But apparently no. I'm sorry!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Did you try...

```xml
<p:chart type="line" model="#{graphique}" rendered="#{graphique != null}"/>
```

Sometimes I had issues with primefaces tags in `<c:if>`